Inconsistencies between gather and equation environments regarding horizontal spacing
I have noticed that the equation and gather environments handle horizontal spacing differently. In the minimal working example below, I use the same exact code inside gather and equation, but the first one does not compactify:
\documentclass[twoside, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2.236068cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\newcommand{\mf}[2]{#1!_{(#2)}}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
    \mf{n}{2} = n \mf{(n - 2)}{2} \,, \enspace \mf{0}{2} = \mf{1}{2} = 1 \,, \enspace n \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \setminus\{1\} \,. 
\end{gather}

\begin{equation}
    \mf{n}{2} = n \mf{(n - 2)}{2} \,, \enspace \mf{0}{2} = \mf{1}{2} = 1 \,, \enspace n \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \setminus\{1\} \,.
\end{equation}

\end{document}

The result is this:

You can see that the first expression is a little too long and it happens to exceed my current margins.
How do I make expressions inside the gather environment to be able to adjust horizontally in the same way as in the equation environment?

Unrelated, but what's the point of fixing the margin with a precision of ten nanometres? :-)

Well, I admit it is small. However, it is JUST outside of the margins in my paper, and I would prefer if I found a way to fix this, rather than change my document. It is the only equation I think that has this error in my entire 50+ page paper, so I will either split it somehow or fix it.

I think (but I'm definitely not sure) the difference is that gather in the end sets its content in \hbox{$\displaystyle...$}, so math glue does not shrink.

It's easy to fix locally, eg remove the \, before the commas or add \! after them, but you can't really make gather automatically apply shrink

I could do that, but that is not the point. There are dozens of equations in my paper and I would like them all to be consistent. If I edited this one differently, I'd have to slightly change all the rest, so I am looking for a way to change the gather environment so that it adjusts spacing automatically every time.
